# -er suffix help

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, gerunds

Is there a word for of nouns with the suffix er but have the base of a verb? Ex. Sleeper, singer, swimmer. a type of noun that performs an action. The closest thing I can find is gerund, but I have been told they must end with "ing". I am attempting to perform a translation.

Answer (score 2):

The general term for such nouns is [**agent noun**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agent%20noun):

> a noun denoting the performer of an action (as *writer*, *inspector*, *patron*, *hanger-on*)

Note, however, that agent nouns don't always end in *er* (as per some of the examples in the definition.)

I know of no term for only *er-suffixed agent nouns*. I suppose you could use the one that I just wrote.

Answer (score 1):

[Deverbal noun](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~vdp/publications/flairs.pdf) is the usual term for nouns formed from verbs by affixation which denote a person filling the agent role with respect to the verb, such as the ones you cite.

But the term is not specific to just -*er* nouns. For example, deverbal nouns can also have an -*or* suffix: “govern ~ governor”, “activate ~ activator”.

Note that 'gerunds' are not deverbal nouns since they are not formed by affixation of the base form of a verb, but are inflected forms of the verb, e.g. "the killing of the seals", where "killing" is the gerund-participle form of the verb "kill".